# Should I implement a smart rewarding agent...?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, pyautogui

So basically, I'm trying to set up an AI agent to learn how to control mouse movements using Tensor-force and pyautogui. I want this agent to be curious and able to respond to different things in the environment. Should I implement a separate agent to control the rewards given to the first agent, and give said second agent a randomized reward based on first agent's actions, or is there already something for agent curiosity in Tensor-force? I've noticed a few things mentioned about action_exploration in Tensor-force's library, but I don't really understand what it's supposed to do...